# drupal7 how to add a same links to field item on post detail page?

Tags: drupal

drupal7 how to add a same links to field item on post detail page?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6lYG.png)

I want add a link to "Posted By" field.

for example :

```
Posted By 
Jack
```

to

```
Posted By 
<a href="google.com" />Jack</a>
```

important thing is 
all posts should be same link ( google.com )

That's why I can't use link field. 
any ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem. 

copy /drupal/modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php file to 

/drupal/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/field/ folder. 

and changed file name to "field--field-submitted-by--content-type.tpl.php"

and edit source code to 

`<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><?php print render($item); ?></a>`

and it works!!!!

this url very helpful.

[link](https://3cwebservices.com/drupal/how-override-field-templates-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

You can overide the output of **"posted by"** field in view.
In overide output we can add token wrapped in a href link.

```
<a href="google.com">[token here]</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!
But, I can't understand. It's not a views page (or block). 
It's post detail page. 
Can I overide just one field in view? for content detail page?

Answer (score 0):

You override your `Posted by` field for particular content type.

Possible override templates are:

```
field.tpl.php
field--field-type.tpl.php
field--field-name.tpl.php
field--content-type.tpl.php
field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
```

Example:- `field--field_posted_by‎--page.tpl.php`
and then write this code to create link in your template file.

```
<?php

if($element['#view_mode'] == "full"){
  print l(render($items),'https://www.google.com');
}
?>
```

I think this may be useful for you.

Thanks,